# Detect if another Chrome app is running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've got a Chrome extension and a Chrome app, which can communicate with each other over messaging.  There are certain actions I want the extension to take only when the Chrome app isn't running.  Given the Chrome app's Id, how can I detect from the Chrome extension if it is running?

I've tried using closed and suspend lifecycle events from the chrome app to assist, but that route isn't seeming possible due to various reasons.  Is there any other way to detect?

Comment: [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management)

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Comment: Define "running" for an app. Has a window open?

Comment: Yes, has a window open.  I've added a hack that works for now (just in my special case, or I'd share), but if there was a better way I'd use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are already using Messaging, so presumably App's event page will wake up to answer if you call it, even if the app is not launched.

You define "running" as having windows open. From the event page, you can [check that](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-getAll):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    /* ... */
    if (chrome.app.window.getAll().length) {
      // Launched
    } else {
      // Not launched
    }
});
```

Comment: Good idea!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
chrome.management.get(appId,function(theapp){
    if(theapp.enabled){
        // it is running
    } else {
        // it is not running
    }
});
```

Comment: My understanding is that enabled and disabled correspond to whether or not the enabled checkbox is checked for the app in the chrome://extensions page, not whether or not it is running.  Is this not true?